# get attribute value where other attribute equals string in simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

Im parsing xml and facing some problems with accessing tags with attributes.
Im trying to get the value of the href attribute of the `<link title="Object">` tag. What i got so far only grabs "MODS Metadata".

**How can i access what i want using simplexml?**

```
    $endpoint = "https://www.nb.no/services/search/v2/search?q=test&itemsPerPage=4";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($endpoint);
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('nb');
    $nbibres = array();
    foreach ($xml->entry as $article) {
      $title =  $article->title;
      $mediatype = $article->children('nb', true)->mediatype;
      $url = $article->link->attributes()->title;
      var_dump($url);    
}
```

**Example entry:**

```
  <entry>
<id>
http://www.nb.no/services/search/v2/search/6a2a78edd1d4a359ccd07ac8310967ff
</id>
<title type="text">Test</title>
<summary type="text"/>
<link title="MODS metadata" rel="via" type="text/xml" href="http://www.nb.no/services/search/v2/mods/6a2a78edd1d4a359ccd07ac8310967ff"/>
<link title="Holdings" rel="related" type="text/xml" href="http://www.nb.no/services/search/v2/holdings/6a2a78edd1d4a359ccd07ac8310967ff"/>
<link title="Object" rel="related" type="text/html" href="http://urn.nb.no/URN:NBN:no-nb_digiebok_110"/>
<link title="Struct" rel="related" type="text/xml" href="http://www.nb.no/services/search/v2/struct/6a2a78edd1d4a359ccd07ac8310967ff"/>
<nb:digital xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">true</nb:digital>
<nb:mainentry xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">Econ Pöyry</nb:mainentry>
<nb:mediatype xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">Bøker</nb:mediatype>
<nb:languages xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">nob</nb:languages>
<nb:isbn xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">9788282321631</nb:isbn>
<nb:urn xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">URN:NBN:no-nb_digiebok_110</nb:urn>
<nb:sesamid xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">6a2a78edd1d4a359ccd07ac8310967ff</nb:sesamid>
<nb:namecreator xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">Econ Pöyry</nb:namecreator>
<nb:namecreators xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">Econ Pöyry</nb:namecreators>
<nb:year xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">2011</nb:year>
<nb:contentclasses xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">restricted</nb:contentclasses>
<nb:metadataclasses xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">public</nb:metadataclasses>
<nb:date xmlns:nb="http://www.nb.no/xml/search/1.0/">2011-01-01</nb:date>
</entry>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Can't you just do the same? I mean, if `$article->title` works, shouldn't `$article->href` work as well?

Comment: There is no ->href tag. there is a link title="object" tag with a href="" i am trying to access

Comment: Quick hint: `$article->link->...` is short-hand for `$article->link[0]->...`, i.e. "the first child called `link`". You can loop through all the `link` elements the same way you loop through the `entry` elements. Alternatively, you can get to grips with XPath.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!